# Jhipster app : mvn package works on terminal but not on intellij

Tags: node.js, maven, intellij-idea, jhipster

I am using nodenv to manage my node versions.
On my jhipster project, when I package my app on my terminal with :

```
mvn package -Pprod -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

It works fine
But when I package the app from Intellij with the same mvn command, I am getting :

```
[INFO]   
[INFO] --- yeoman-maven-plugin:0.5:build (run-frontend-build) @ tecfel ---  
[INFO] node version :  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Total time: 5.429 s  
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-14T14:12:04+01:00  
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/541M  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.5:build (run-frontend-build) on project tecfel: Error during : node --version: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/home/myApp/Documents/workspace/tecfel"): error=2, Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type -> [Help 1]  
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.5:build (run-frontend-build) on project tecfel: Error during : node --version  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)  
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)  
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)  
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)  
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)  
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)  
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during : node --version  
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:129)  
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.logToolVersion(YeomanMojo.java:105)  
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.npmInstall(YeomanMojo.java:84)  
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.execute(YeomanMojo.java:68)  
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
```

Does any one knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that IntelliJ does not use nodenv.

You seem to run a very old version of JHipster build process as we have stopped using yeoman-maven-plugin a long time ago, consider updating your project or at least copy/inspire from a recent generated project that use https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin The main benefit from using this plugin is that in prod profile it uses its own copy of node/npm binaries installed in your project and so is completely isolated from your running context.